# Probabilistic fragmentation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have the following problem:

We start with an interval of length $1$ and break it into two intervals of lengths $r$ and $1-r$, where $r$ is a random variable in $[0,1]$ with probability density function $\eta(r)$. For example choose $\eta(r)=1$ and we break the interval at a uniform random position.

Now any interval that is remaining and is larger than $x_c$, a fixed threshold $0<x_c<1$, again breaks according to the same rule that is if the current length of the interval is $x_i>x_c$ it will break into $x_i r$ and $x_i(1-r)$. All the $r$'s are independent of each other but with the same $\eta(r)$.

Continue until no interval of length $x>x_c$ exists.

What is the final average number of fragments with size less than $x$, denoted $C(x)$. Clearly $C(x)$ for $x>x_c$ is equal to $C(x_c)$ so it is sufficient to find $C(x)$ for $0\leq x\leq x_c$.

I asked myself this question while reading ["Phase transition in a random fragmentation problem with applications to computer science"](http://lptms.u-psud.fr/satya-majumdar/files/2010/12/dean02.pdf) where the authors look at a generalised fragmentation process of breaking an interval into $m$ pieces and analyse the average number of interval splits.

Comment: So you're asking for the expectation of $C(x)$? Or what?

Comment: In my notation $C(x)$ is already the expectation of the final number of intervals with lengths $\leq x$.